# Switching tires from larger to smaller

Tags: mountain-bike

I have a 29" tire on my mountain bike and want to know if 
I can I use or switch to a 27.5" mountain bike tire?

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve. If you are using a wide 29" switching to a narrower 29" might be beneficial.

Comment: The general answer is to look at the ISO size on the tires.  29 inch tires will have a number on the side like 44-622.  Any other tire with the identical second number and a roughly equal first number (maybe anywhere from 30 to 60) will generally fit, if the tire isn't so fat that it rubs the frame.  But if the second numbers differ you can't expect to pull off the swap.  Pretty much all 29" inch tires, some labeled 28", and all "700c" tires have a 622 second number.

Comment: Please clarify - will you replace the whole wheel (rim, spokes, hub, tyre, etc) or just a tyre?  Question suggests you want to decrease the radius of the tyre and not change the rim ?

Comment: @kenneth a. You would need to replace the whole wheel assembly, you can't just swap tires over. If you did put a 27.5 wheel / tire in you will also alter the geometry of the bike to some degree. Out of curiosity why do you want smaller wheels? It's much easier to put on most 700c tires to a 29" wheel.

Answer (score 5):

No. 29" tires fit on larger wheels than 27.5".

In principle you can switch to smaller wheels if your bike has disc brakes, but that will lead to other problems with ground clearance and handling.

Comment: I think the OP means smaller rims *and* tires together as a whole wheel package, not just smaller tires.

Comment: They might, and I included the option in the answer.